# Android META-INF size in apk is very large

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, meta-inf

I using some native library in my app. in apk file under META-INF folder is a folder named "native" and in this folder is large files that seems related to Widows and Mac OS.
please see this image:

[image]

my questions is:
what is these files?
can I delete them?
if yes how?

Comment: Hard to tell where it's coming from without more info, but it's almost certainly not supposed to be there...probably one of your dependencies messed up their packaging.

Comment: I suspect your dependency on conscrypt is not an Android library and is not meant for use in an Android app. Files shouldn't be placed in the META-INF as they would not be covered by the signature of your app (the v1 jar signing scheme).

Answer (score 0):

I don't found out why this files exist in my app but adding this line in app level gradle file solved problem:

```
android {
    ...

    packagingOptions {
        ...

        exclude 'META-INF/native/*'
    }
}
```

thanks to Ryan M and Pierre